# positioning an image using HTML

Tags: html, alignment

Lets say I have an image and I would like to position it not exactly at the center nor at right, what html code I should be using to do this?

I want to put the exact position I want instead of using `center` or `right` or `left`.

Thanks

Comment: okay how about if it's css? what code I should be using?

Comment: See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use at least a little bit of CSS. With inline CSS it is easy to use (but maybe not the best way doing it inline).

So use the `style` attribute in HTML and set the position with CSS.

```
style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:10px;"
```

With `position:fixed; ...` you can set the image always at the same position of your screen, even when you are scolling down the page.

Comment: thanks so much. This is helpful and I've also tried it with CSS and it's working fine too. It's just a simple html so I didn't create a css for it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
<img style="position: absolute; right: 30%; top: 25%;" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NVum7/

I think you probably want to learn about CSS positioning:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/

Answer (score 0):

Using margins and Padding via CSS. Look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp).